# Words like Schadenfreude or Sauerkraut

Tags: translation, loanwords

What are some composite German words such as "Schadenfreude" or "Sauerkraut" that are commonly used in English and with no English equivalents?

Comment: Before this question gets blitzed with comments and goes kaput, I'll point you to [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_German_expressions_in_English). :^)

Comment: @J.R. Why would the question go kaputt!?

Comment: Because Beiherhund das Oder die Flipperwaldt gersput, of course.

Comment: @Spatz: I have a hunch it might get closed; it's a bit open-ended. _Kaput_, of course, was only meant to convey my hunch by using one of the words from the list.

Comment: Fahrvergnügen (from a VW commercial), Autobahn, Eigenwert, Zugszwang, Poltergeist, Hinterland, Blitzkrieg ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Zeitgeist
- Weltschmerz
- Doppelgänger
- Delikatessen

For the usage frequency of these over time, see [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Weltschmerz%2CZeitgeist%2CDoppelg%C3%A4nger%2CDelikatessen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Also in a purely philosophical context, there is [“Dasein”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasein) which is often left intentionally untranslated.

Comment: *Delikatessen* is not a composite word.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Delikat - delicate, essen - eating

Comment: @Mitch: But that’s not the origin of *Delikatessen.* Rather [it’s derived from the French *délicatesse*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Delikatesse#German) (see also [here](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Delikatesse)). It doesn’t even work as a folk etymology, as *Delikatessen* would be pronounced differently, if it were a composite word.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft hilarious! I had no idea!